# show autocomplete suggestions only with street and number

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have this code for google autocomplete:

```
// Google Autocomplete Addresses
let autocomplete;
var street;
var streetNumber;
var city;
var zip;
  
function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.querySelector("#autocompleteAddress"), {
    componentRestrictions: { country: ["de", "DE"] },
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
    types: ["address"],
  });
  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
}
  
function fillInAddress() {
    
  const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  
  for (const component of place.address_components) {
    
    switch (component.types[0]) {   
      
      case "route":
        street = component.long_name;
        $( "#street" ).val( street )
        break;
      
      
      case "street_number":
        streetNumber = component.long_name
        $("#streetnumber").val( streetNumber )
        break;
       
  
      case "postal_code":
        plz = component.long_name;
        $("#zip").val( plz )
        break;


      case "locality":
        city = component.long_name;
        $("#city").val( city )
      break;

    }
  }
  
  $("#autocompleteAddress").val( street + " " + streetNumber)
         
}
```

This works fine, but not perfectly
My problem: If you only write the streetname, you get the suggestions:

[image]

If you now pick a suggestion, I get no streetnumber and no zip code (logically):

[image]

how can i display the suggestions only after street and house number have been entered (a string and a number)?

Thanks!